# incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) in jdk11.0.16

Tags: java, generics, java-11

I am getting below error while compiling my source code in jdk11.0.16 , kindly help me to resolve this

ERROR:

```
inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
[ERROR]     inferred: MessageHandler<? extends capture#1 of ? extends BootstrapContext>
[ERROR]     upper bound(s): MessageHandler<? extends capture#1 of ? extends BootstrapContext>,MessageHandler<B>
```

CODE snippet:

```
public interface Test2 {
    <B extends BootstrapContext, T extends MessageHandler<? extends B>> T getMessageHandlerForContext(final Class<? extends B> type);
}


class Test implements Test2 {
    private final Map<Class<? extends BootstrapContext>, MessageHandler<?>> handlers =
          new HashMap<Class<? extends BootstrapContext>, MessageHandler<?>>();
          
    @Override
    public <B extends BootstrapContext, T extends MessageHandler<? extends B>> T getMessageHandlerForContext(
        final Class<? extends B> type) {
      return (T) handlers.get(type);
    }
}      
      
public interface MessageHandler<B extends BootstrapContext> {
    void init(B bootContext);
    void stop();
}

public interface BootstrapContext {
    
}
```

Comment: Your class `Test` override `getMessageHandlerForContext`, can you include the base class also?

Comment: Test implements Test2

public interface Test2 {
  <B extends BootstrapContext, T extends MessageHandler<? extends B>> T getMessageHandlerForContext(
      final Class<? extends B> type);
} @samabcde

Comment: @samabcde any help?

Comment: I can't see the mentioned error after adding `Test2`, where do you see the error message(or what trigger it)?

Comment: final MessageHandler<B> handler = test.getMessageHandlerForContext(context.getClass()); @samabcde if you call the method like this you will get issue

Comment: Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Even I got your last comment, I still can't reproduce the error(B is not known to me). Although you can see the error easily, keep in mind that reader like me can only refer to what you put here. If your problem is so difficult to reproduce, people are less willing to help you.

Comment: If you have a question about a compiler error, the minimum should be to post the code that causes the compiler error.